# Re-render DOM if index of data elements changed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Vue.js doesnt detect that i swap 2 array elements in my data object:

```
data: {
  list: [
    'Foo',
    'Bar',
    'Test'
  ]
}
```

Method to swap entries:

```
swapIndex: function(from, to) {

  var first = this.list[from];
  this.list[from] = this.list[to];
  this.list[to] = first;

}
```

**JsFiddle** https://jsfiddle.net/aaroniker/r11hxce8/

I want re-render the `v-for` loop if i swap the indexies.

Thanks!

Comment: You have to use mutation methods to make these array changes reactive. Check the [documentation for array change detection](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the solution I came with. I created a copy of your list to modify it, and I invoked the `this.$set()` method on the list:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        list: [
            'Foo',
            'Bar',
            'Test'
        ]
    },
    methods: {
        swapIndex: function(from, to) {
            var copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.list))
            var first = copy[from];
            copy[from] = copy[to];
            copy[to] = first;
            this.$set(this,'list',copy)
            console.log(this.list);

        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

[Changing value in an array with the `[]` operator won't let vue detect the change](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats), replacing the array is one way to solve this, or you can use the slightly better solution of `arr.splice(index, 1, newVal)` suggested by the guide.